# Display a pdf file in phonegap 3 application

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, pdf, cordova

I am looking for an example code for working with pdf file on a phonegap + jquery mobile application

I have a list of pdf files some are on the devise and some are online.

when user clicks a button i need to open the pdf file inside the application

the page that will show the pdf file will have the header and footer of the application and will have options like search, zoom, scroll pages, bookmarks

I try with inAppBrowser / childBrowser / pdf.js / viewer.js but cant seem to make it work

It is a week now that I am trying everything and cant get any progress done

I see that there are lots of discussions about this and not one clear answer

So please if there is a good example for phonegap please help here

Thank you all.

Comment: take a look at this: https://github.com/markeeftb/FileOpener

Comment: Hey Shahe, this will open the file externally not in the Application view. I am looking to open the pdf file internally - in the app view and not open an external app like adobe reader

Comment: I think you should develop something custom in order to be able to do that my friend

Comment: Ok but where to start?